# octal to binary for 12 digit numbers in excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to convert a 12 digit octal number to binary

But looks like excel's inbuilt function OCT2Bin wont work for numbers greater than 517

So I tried to split the numbers and concatenate them, but it didn't work

I tried

```
=OCT2BIN(MID(A2,1,2))&OCT2BIN(MID(A2,3,2))&OCT2BIN(MID(A2,5,2))&OCT2BIN(MID(A2,7,2))&OCT2BIN(MID(A2,9,2))&OCT2BIN(MID(A2,11,2))
```

For example Octal to binary of the number

```
123456765432
```

is

```
1010011100101110111110101100011010
```

but my formula is returning

```
101011100101110111110101100110100
```

I understand that the formula is not working because I shouldn't be breaking the numbers and concatenate them. But I am not sure how to handle it in excel

is there a way to convert 12 digit octal numbers to binary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenating the function is no problem because every digit in an octal number represents exactly 3 digits in binary.
Your problem is that leading zeros are omitted, e.g. in your example 34o = 011100 but the first 0 is not returned so you only concatenate 11100. The OCT2BIN function has another argument in which you can determine the number of digits returned:

```
OCT2BIN(34) = 11100
OCT2BIN(34, 6) = 011100
```

As of performance: you can convert 3 octal digits at once instead of only 2.

Comment: Thanks Jan, 3 digits might get values greater than 517

Comment: @vignesh The Maximum value for 3 digits in octal is 777 which equals 511 in decimal

Comment: Thanks Jan
I also wanted to convert first 27 bits of the binary to decimal and I tried this, it doesnt seem to work
=BIN2DEC(MID(B2,1,9))&BIN2DEC(MID(B2,10,9))&BIN2DEC(MID(B2,20,9))
any idea why it isn't working?

Comment: @vignesh Converting from binary to decimal you cannont concatenate the results because the amount of digits in one system is not proportional to the other (unlike binary and octal where one octal digit always equals 3 binary digits). 
Im not sure if there is an efficient way in vba. 
A workaround: convert your binary to octal (or use your existing octal values) and convert those to decimal using oct2dec. oct2dec accepts octal values of up to 30 bits which would be sufficient for your needs.

Answer (score 4):

Since `excel-vba` is also tagged, using VBA this could be solved more general at all.

```
Public Function myDec2Bin(ByVal decValue As Double) As String
 Select Case decValue
  Case 0
   myDec2Bin = "0"
  Case 1
   myDec2Bin = "1"
  Case Else
   myDec2Bin = myDec2Bin(Int(decValue / 2)) & IIf(decValue / 2 = Int(decValue / 2), "0", "1")
 End Select
End Function

Public Function myOct2Dec(octValue As String) As Double
 Dim decValue As Double
 For i = 0 To Len(octValue) - 1
  decValue = decValue + Mid(octValue, i + 1, 1) * (8 ^ (Len(octValue) - 1 - i))
 Next
 myOct2Dec = decValue
End Function

Public Function myOct2Bin(octValue As String) As String
 Dim decValue As Double
 decValue = myOct2Dec(octValue)
 myOct2Bin = myDec2Bin(decValue)
End Function
```

Those `UDF` can all be used as cell formulas like:

```
=myOct2Bin(A2)
```

Answer (score 2):

try this , i have checked the result[image]

Comment: Thanks, upvoted.  I also wanted to convert first 27 bits of the binary to decimal and I tried this, it doesnt seem to work =BIN2DEC(MID(B2,1,9))&BIN2DEC(MID(B2,10,9))&BIN2DEC(MID(B2,2‌​0,9)) any idea why it isn't working?