# Binary to Decimal conversion for 27 digits

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to convert binary digit that is 27 characters long

```
BIN2DEC(B2)
```

Didn't work

I also tried

```
=BIN2DEC(MID(B3,1,9))&BIN2DEC(MID(B3,10,9))&BIN2DEC(MID(B3,20,9))
```

The number I am trying is

```
001010011100101110111110101
```

The answer I am getting is

```
83302491
```

Where as the right answer is

```
21913077
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [octal to binary for 12 digit numbers in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41532063/octal-to-binary-for-12-digit-numbers-in-excel) I have provided a `UDF` `Public Function myOct2Dec(octValue As String) As Double` already. Have you tried to understand how it works? If you understand that, then you can adapt this to an Bin to Dec conversion also:

```
Public Function myBin2Dec(binValue As String) As Double
 Dim decValue As Double
 For i = 0 To Len(binValue) - 1
  decValue = decValue + Mid(binValue, i + 1, 1) * (2 ^ (Len(binValue) - 1 - i))
 Next
 myBin2Dec = decValue
End Function
```

Use it like

```
=myBin2Dec(B2)
```

Using a formula you cannot simply concatenate splitted results together. With converting octal from/to binary this is possible because 8^0 = 2^0, 8^1 = 2^3, 8^2 = 2^6, ... So exactly 3 binary digits are needed for one octal digit. But with converting decimal from/to binary such is not possible. 10^0 = 2^0, 10^1 = 2^?.

So your formula must take into account that the leftmost 9 binary digits must be multiplied with 2^0, the next 9 digits from right to left must be multiplied with 2^9, the next 9 digits from right to left must be multiplied with 2^18.

```
=BIN2DEC(MID(B2,1,9))*2^18+BIN2DEC(MID(B2,10,9))*2^9+BIN2DEC(MID(B2,19,9))
```

But this is really very static since it only works for binary values in exact length of 27 (3 parts of 9 digits).

Comment: Thanks for the help Axel!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a VBA version which bootstraps existing worksheet functions. It converts binary to hex and then lets the worksheet function converts from hex to decimal:

```
Function Binary2Dec(ByVal s As String) As Variant
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, r As Long
    Dim h As String

    n = Len(s)
    r = n Mod 4
    If r > 0 Then s = String(4 - r, "0") & s 'now the length of s is a multiple of 4
    n = Len(s)
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        For i = 1 To n - 3 Step 4
            h = h & .Bin2Hex(Mid(s, i, 4))
        Next i
        Binary2Dec = CDec(.Hex2Dec(h))
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't need VBA and will work for various length inputs:

```
=SUM(VALUE(MID(B3,ROW(OFFSET($A$1,0,0,LEN(B3))),1))/(2^ROW(OFFSET($A$1,0,0,LEN(B3)))))*2^LEN(B3)
```

It needs to be entered as a single-cell array formula (i.e. [F2] then type/paste the formula then [ctrl-shift-enter])